# Quill.js editor not showing up

Tags: javascript, quill

So, I am creating a web app that uses Quill.js on Google Apps Script. This is my code (currently):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Quotix</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.7/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.9.1/showdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/turndown@6.0.0/dist/turndown.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.7/quill.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var converters = {
        showdown: new showdown.Converter(),
        turndown: new TurndownService()
      };

      var Delta = Quill.import('delta');

      var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
        modules: {
          toolbar: {
            container: '#toolbar'
          }
        },
        theme: 'snow'
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="editor-container">
      <div id="toolbar">
        <select class="ql-font">
          <option value="open-sans" selected>Open Sans</option>
          <option value="merriweather">Merriweather</option>
          <option value="fira-mono">Fira Mono</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="editor"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is **supposed** to show a rich text editor, but instead I get this:
[image: This is what I got]

Can you please help me get the rich text editor to show up? I have looked up how to solve this problem **many** times!!!

Comment: try putting your script tag containing QuillJS stuff as the last tag of <body> (place after #editor-container)? As #editor and #toolbar may not have rendered yet when the <head> script is run

Comment: Thank you! It is working now